# Add data into two table connected with id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Hi here I have this code to insert data to mysql database into table `radnici` :

```
 try {        
                $STH = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO radnici (ime_prezime, jmbg, grad, ulica, posta, telefon, uloga, email, user_id) VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9)");

                $STH->bindParam(':1', $_POST['ime']);
                $STH->bindParam(':2', $_POST['jmbg']);
                $STH->bindParam(':3', $_POST['grad']);
                $STH->bindParam(':4', $_POST['ulica']);
                $STH->bindParam(':5', $_POST['posta']);
                $STH->bindParam(':6', $_POST['telefon']);
                $STH->bindParam(':7', $_POST['pozicija']);
                $STH->bindParam(':8', $_POST['email']);
                $STH->bindParam(':9', $user_id);

//HERE I NEED TO INSERT DATA TO TABLE WORKHOURS BUT CONNECTED WITH JUST ADDEDED ID
//SO here I NEED query something like this // INSERT INTO radnici (ID, ID_radnici, ime_prezime, jmbg,... here ID_radnici is =with ID from table radnici of added data


                $STH->execute();

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            echo "<p>Data submitted successfully</p>";
```

So now when I add this I need to add into this table `workhours` data but connected with ID with just added data...

so in second table I have: `ID, ID_radnici (here I must add ID_radnici same value as ID on table radnici), value, user_id`

**I write this but DONT work: 
UPDATE:**

```
 try {        
                $STH = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO radnici (ime_prezime, jmbg, grad, ulica, posta, telefon, uloga, email, user_id) VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9)");

                $STH->bindParam(':1', $_POST['ime']);
                $STH->bindParam(':2', $_POST['jmbg']);
                $STH->bindParam(':3', $_POST['grad']);
                $STH->bindParam(':4', $_POST['ulica']);
                $STH->bindParam(':5', $_POST['posta']);
                $STH->bindParam(':6', $_POST['telefon']);
                $STH->bindParam(':7', $_POST['pozicija']);
                $STH->bindParam(':8', $_POST['email']);
                $STH->bindParam(':9', $user_id);

                $orderID = $db -> lastInsertId();

   $STH1 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO workhours (ID_radnika) values($orderID)");  // where $value is the value you want to insert...
   $STH->execute();
      $STH1->execute();






            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        echo "<p>Data submitted successfully</p>";
```

Comment: maybe lastinsertID can be solution for this?

Comment: Since you're not using mysql, you might not want to tag the question as such...

Comment: @RyanJ It clearly is mysql, just not using php's mysql functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lastInsertId()` and insert your data into the other table using the value returned from it.

Something like this:

```
int $lastID = $db->lastInsertId();
if ( $lastID ) {
   $STH = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO workhours (ID_radnici, value, userid) values($lastID, $value, $user_id)");  // where $value is the value you want to insert...
   $STH->execute();
}
```

Comment: but I use php pdo, not mysql functions

Comment: As @Andrew said, he's using PDO, not standard mysql functions (as they are deprecated and allow for multiple security risks). PDO or mysql_i are much better solutions

Comment: You can't get the last inserted ID before you execute the query. Execute the first query first, then call lastInsertId()

Answer (score 1):

Using lastInsertId will do what you want:

```
$orderID = $db -> lastInsertId();
```